# Installed SQL server management studio 2012, but there are no instances running

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012-express

So, as it says, I installed sql server (2012 express), and during installation I checked the option LocalDB. Now I'm trying to connect to the database engine, but can't. I've tried connecting with windows authentication (to local, and localhost), with sa-user and no password and a bunch of other stuff.

When I visit the configuration tool and try to se what my instance is called, I see a new problem. There's nothing running at all. Under SQL Server configuration manager (local) --> SQL Server Services there's nothing.

What am I missing? Obviously I've missed som step where I start something up, but for the life of me I don't know what.
Help!

Comment: Open up services.msc, have a look at the SQL Server services, what **exact** ones are listed?

Comment: The point about LocalDB is, that there is no service. Have a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms233817%28VS.110%29.aspx

Comment: did you only install client tools or you also install SQL service?

Comment: @Arran It's completely empty, "there are no items to show in this view"

Comment: @Mithrandir Ok, I'm not sure I completely understand, but what does that mean, how do I connect to my database engine?

Comment: @Hardik I don't know, what's the diffenrence?

Answer (score 3):

just use `localhost\sqlexpress` with `Windows Authentication`

You can also Try `.\SQLExpress`

Answer (score 2):

http://www.stratospher.es/blog/post/connecting-to-localdb-with-sql-server-management-studio-2012-ssms

> LocalDB doesn't create any database services; LocalDB processes are started and stopped automatically when needed. The application is just connecting to "Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0" and LocalDB process is started as a child process of the application. A few minutes after the last connection to this process is closed the process shuts down.

Comment: file not found.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and was able to connect using (localdb)\v11.0 with Windows Authentication.